'statusCode': 401, error with aiohttp et asyncio, ChatGPT request
I'm trying to make a simple request using azure.openai chatGPT, i setup a simple code but i always get a 401 return error:
{'statusCode': 401, 'message': 'Unauthorized. Access token is missing, invalid, audience is incorrect (https://cognitiveservices.azure.com), or have expired.'}
I previously got 404 error because my api version was not the good one but this configuration is working with openai package. Any clue?
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def chatGPT_call():
    # Load your API key, endpoint, and deployment id from an environment variable or secret management service
    api_key = "MY API KEY"  # Replace with your actual API key
    endpoint = "MY ENVIRONMENT.openai.azure.com"  # Replace with your actual endpoint
    deployment_id = "https://MY GPT ID"  # Replace with your actual deployment ID

    # Prepare the request payload
    url = f"https://{endpoint}/openai/deployments/{deployment_id}/chat/completions?api-version=2024-07-01-preview"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
        
    }
    payload = {
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "system",
                "content": "you're a helpful assistant that talks like a pirate"
            },
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": "can you tell me how to care for a parrot?"
            }
        ]
    }

    # Send the request to the API
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload) as response:
                result = await response.json()
        return result        
        return result["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

# Example usage of the function
async def main():
    response = await chatGPT_call()
    print(response)

# Run the async function
asyncio.run(main())


Hi @5zigen, have you tried using the langchain_openai python library (especially the class AzureChatOpenAI) ?

Try using params or a pre-encoded URL: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls

Maybe you need : after Bearer?
